# ios5 error when trying to shorten a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, substring

I have this string: "str is {(
    You,
    Me
)}"

Looking on SO, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082178/objective-c-remove-last-character-from-string) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072556/how-to-delete-single-characters-in-an-uitextview) (among others)

I want to remove the leading {( and the trailing )}

Every solution so far has been met with an error:

```
-[__NSCFSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

or a similar variant. I can print the value to the console and I can use the unfiltered "peopleExport" elsewhere in my app.

The code I've tried so far includes :

```
NSString *str = (NSString *)[managedObject valueForKeyPath:@"people.name"];

    NSLog(@"str is %@", str);

    //NSString *string = @"hello one two three";

    //NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:3];
    str = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, str.length-2)];


    NSString *newStr;

    if ( [str length] > 0){
        NSLog(@"a");
    newStr = [str substringFromIndex:2];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"b");
        newStr = str;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", newStr);

    peopleExport = newStr;
```

The source is from a core data store. Does that matter?

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Are you sure it's a string coming out of coredata? It looks like you are trying to cast a NSSet to a NSString.

Comment: The contents of the NSSet will depend on your data model. Usually an NSSet will contain the entities at the end of a to-many relationship. What does your data model look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `str` is not actually an `NSString`, but is an `NSSet`, and what you're seeing is the result of the `-description` method being called on that set. If what you want is a string of the form "You, Me", try this:

```
NSSet *set = [managedObject valueForKeyPath:@"people.name"];
NSString *newString = [[set allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: You guys are great.. That was it.. I will mark you all up, but I will give Wevah the answer as I used his code. Thank you all!!